# Calculate BMI in Textpad using Java

Tags: java, textpad

I'm supposed to design a program in TextPad to calculate BMI. I can't get the program to calculate the bmi using the formula. This is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class BmiCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print("Enter weight in pounds: ");
     double weightInPounds = keyboard.nextDouble();
     System.out.print("Enter height in inches: ");
     double heightInInches = keyboard.nextDouble();


      double bmi =  weightInPounds/(heightInInches * heightInInches) * 703;

      System.out.println("Your body mass index is" + bmi);
    }
  }
```

The output shows:

Enter weight in pounds: 130

Enter height in inches: 66

Your body mass index

Nothing shows for the bmi when I run the program. I compiled the program and TextPad shows no errors. I don't know what is wrong with my code. Can anyone find the error in the code?

Comment: You didnt ask anything or even throw up an error message? What do you want?

Answer (score 3):

You're misusing [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). You should either use string concatenation:

```
System.out.println("Your body mass index is" + bmi);
```

or use a correct format string that uses the BMI you pass:

```
System.out.printf("Your body mass index is %f", + bmi);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured it out. TextPad couldn't read my equation for bmi. Once I changed it I got the right output.